# deploy web app on softlayer

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat7, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have tried to search online for hours but unable to find a correct guide on deploying a web application on softlayer bare metal server.

My web app is developed in JAVA and the web server I use is tomcat7. I already exported the application into a war file from my eclipse IDE.

Now I am not sure how I can proceed. Any help is deeply appreciated! Much thanks in advance!
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can help you, would be to order a VM with MySQL, once it's done you will have to install Tomcat on it and deploy your web app (war file) to it. Also you could buy a certificate to run https since self-certificate are not supported.
There's also some other add ons that you might be interested on, and you can see them when you're placing an order.

The next link can help you with the database:
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/databases

Hope it helps.